# Function without return value

Tags: javascript, function, return, return-value

In javascript, why does this code work?

```
var myVar=setInterval(
   function(){
      myTimer()
   },1000
);

function myTimer()
{
   var d=new Date();
   var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t; //displays time
   dpcument.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = myVar; //displays 1
}
```

Why does `myVar` hold the value `1` even if I am not returning anything from the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a value, not your function.  It returns an `intervalID`, so you can clear it with `clearTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

`myVar` holds the return value of the call to `setInterval` irrespective of the fact that you have declared an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

`myVar` will take the return value of the call to `setInterval`, not of the anonymous function you're passing, neither from `myTimer`.

Here is how it works:

1. You call `setInterval`, which returns a timer id. You pass it a reference to an anonymous function.
2. When the interval expires, the anonymous function is called (internally). It returns undefined (but it doesn't matter, since it's called internally, and that return value is never used).
3. Every time the anonymous function is invoked, it calls `myTimer`, which also returns undefined. That is never used inside your anonymous function.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: I'd like to know what's wrong with my first sentence.